# How do I convert datetime format?

Tags: javascript

**How do I convert datetime format into *2012-02-22T11:34:00.000+0000* ?**

I wan to convert datetime format into this format as shown below :

```
year-month-dayT10:45:00.000+0000
```

Example :

```
2012-02-22T11:34:00.000+0000
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: Hi ross presser i am getting result as "18-7-2014" but i need to get result as "2012-02-22T11:34:00.000+0000"

Answer (score 0):

By passing general date in this function yoou can do it.

```
function getDateFormat(generalDate){
var sapDate = '0000-00-00T00:00:00';
   var date;
   if (!generalDate) {
       //NOP
   } else if(typeof generalDate == "string"){
    var dateArray = generalDate.split("-");
    if(dateArray.length < 2)
     dateArray = generalDate.split("/");
   date = new Date(monthNumber[dateArray[1]]+"/"+dateArray[0]+"/"+dateArray[2]);
   } else {
       date = new Date((generalDate.getTime() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)) + 19800000);
   }

   if (date) {
       var monthIn =null;
       if(date.getMonth() < 9)
           monthIn = "0"+(date.getMonth()+1);
       else
           monthIn = date.getMonth()+1;

       var date2 = date.getDate();
       if(date2 <= 9)
           date2 = "0"+date2;

       sapDate = date.getFullYear()+'-'+monthIn+'-'+date2+'T00:00:00.000+0000';
   }

console.log(sapDate);
}
```

The working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3kHXV/)

Comment: can i use only javascript and run without using html tags in fiddle?? I am new to javascript and fuddle i am unable to use it?? will i need to write code in html to run and print ?? can u please help me out

Comment: This is what i have done in my fiddle . click on the above link you will see that i have not used any html tag. It is only java script that i have used.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. U said "By passing general date in this function yoou can do it." i passed same but only in top of function in 1st line but after running i am getting blank screen nothing is displaying. Can u please say in what lines did i need to change "general date" and i can get the output. Even now i am getting blank screen

Comment: I insist you to please see the fiddle link that i have posted. here as a parameter of getDateFormat function i have passed new Date() which contains today date and time. For your output see the result in console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
var myDate = new Date();

var date = myDate.getDate();
var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1; 

var year = myDate.getFullYear();
var h = myDate.getHours();
var m = myDate.getMinutes();
var s = myDate.getSeconds();
var ms = myDate.getMilliseconds();
document.write(year + "-" + month + "-" + date + "T" + "-" + h + ":" + m + ":" + s + "." + ms);

</script>
```